# Seeking free, publicly available GIS data for Singapore?

Tags: data, singapore

Are there any free, publicly available datasets for Singapore?

I've examined [Openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), [Global Admin Boundaries](http://www.gadm.org/), [GRUMP](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/gpw/wps.jsp) and the [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) datasets, but I'm interested in vector data of higher resolution and or any type of census information.

Comment: Is there a specific type of data you're looking for (road network, population distribution, &c)?

Comment: Yes - I am interested in population data, land-use zoning and buildings (although I realise that is unlikely). Road networks would also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

**Lots of Spatial Data for Singapore**

Table data
https://data.gov.sg/dataset/resident-population-by-ethnicity-gender-and-age-group?view_id=8ff89d3f-48c8-46e4-8a4d-a8b9f152976f&resource_id=f9dbfc75-a2dc-42af-9f50-425e4107ae84

and Census Data

http://www.onemap.sg/index.html?PopulationQuery

Web Mapping available here:

[image]

http://www.onemap.sg/index.html

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified that I am interested in free data (I think 'public' is ambiguous). Unfortunately these data sources are incredibly expensive.

Comment: Both links are currently broken

Comment: updated links - If you search the sites they have the data - sites change over 5 years

Answer (score 2):

From the Singapore 2014 Master Plan:

- [Planning Area Boundary](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/master-plan-2014-planning-area-boundary) (55 planning areas)

The above is provided in KML. The above also links to Region Boundary (5 regions) and the more granular Subzone Boundary files (323 subzones).

There's also the [Planning Area Census 2010](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/planning-area-census-2010) (also in KML) which has more useful polygon labels, although they're embedded in markup, e.g.:

`<p><font color="red"><i></i> <b>Planning Area Name - JURONG WEST</b> </font></p> <p><font color="Blue"><i></i> <b>Region Name - WEST REGION</b> </font></p>`

Nevertheless, that's better than the Master Plan KML files which only have labels like `62436.23535`.

Finally, Singstat (www.singstat.gov.sg/statistics/browse-by-theme/geographic-distribution) has useful datasets by geography covering a variety of topics including census figures.

Comment: All links are 404.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still on the look out. The data you are requesting for is available in https://data.gov.sg. For infrastructure you may want to look here [Infrastructure Data](https://data.gov.sg/search?q=infrastructure). You can also find the data for [transportation](https://data.gov.sg/search?q=transportation&groups=transport) and [population](https://data.gov.sg/group/society).