# Seeking Singapore postal districts boundaries?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, singapore

Does anyone know where to get GIS data for Singapore postal boundaries?

I need a shape or KML file which I can then overlay onto google maps to show a neighbourhood break down of Singapore.

Comment: It is expensive to purchase http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17676/gis-data-for-singapore