# How to create/obtain district data for Singapore?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps, geojson, singapore

I am newbie in GIS and have started using QGIS. I am hoping to map all districts of Singapore and create a Shapefile and get GeoJSON details for all districts. I am not able to find that currently.

So what I thought of doing after looking on internet is:

- Get a base map layer (something like Google Map OR OpenStreetMap) and load in QGIS using Plugins
- Load another image file  on top of it which has districts mapped to it.
- Make that image file layer transparent with borders.
- Create polygons for each districts
- Save that as Shapefile and export as GeoJSON

This is what I thought based on tutorial I followed.

https://github.com/mtop/speciesgeocoder/wiki/Tutorial-for-creating-polygons-in-QGIS

But, this was done for the entire world map. How can I do it for Singapore as I am not able to find TIFF file for Singapore districts.

I only have shapefile for Singapore country.

Comment: Have you investigated whether OpenStreetMap already has district boundaries for Singapore?  If it does then perhaps your question to research/ask should be "how to extract Singapore district boundaries from OpenStreetMap to shapefile?"

Comment: Yes, I did try that. But I did not see the district boundaries in OSM. https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/536780#map=12/1.3690/103.7992&layers=T

Comment: Your methodology seems correct. It sounds like your *real* question is how/where to find a map or data that shows the districts of Singapore. If you know what the boundaries should be, you can load in a basemap or imagery and use that as reference to outline them. Otherwise you can't really map what you don't have a source for. I don't know if they are in OSM or not (they'd be administrative level probably 4 or higher) but a Google search does turn up numerous maps: http://www.sghomeonline.com/singapore-district-guide/

Comment: Yes, That is what I tried. I loaded basemap as 'Google Maps'. Then when I try to load the 'Image with boundaries', I do not see that being overlay on my basemap. I am adding 'Image with boundaries' as Add Raster layer. Is that correct?

Comment: That depends on your source image. If it contains georeferencing information (ie a GeoTIFF, or something with an accompanying world file), then it should come in and line up though you may need to do a projection conversion/transformation if its coordinate system is different than your map (and Google uses a pseudomercator projection if that's what you're using as a base/project projection). If you grab just a random image like a screenshot of what I linked to or something without position information, you'd have to first georeference it yourself to get it to line up.

Comment: It is not clear where you are currently stuck in your efforts to try and create a shapefile of Singapore district boundaries.  Would you be able to [edit] your question to describe what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?  If the focus of your question is finding rather than creating a shapefile of Singapore district boundaries then it would appear to be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94942/seeking-singapore-postal-districts-boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the online service from OSM user wambacher via
https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/

Search the tree structure on the left screen, or the text search box, for Singapore ... you can unfold each entry to discover all sub boundaries.
Pay attention to the number of admistrative level behind each entry.

About Singapore it seems that there are five districts available as boundary relation inside OSM data. Are those detailed enough for your purposes?

You can export each boundary in different formats, see options at bottom screen.

Pay attention to OSM data licence conditions if you want to use that public.

Comment: I dont think so that would be enough. Singapore is divided in 28 districts

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Answer (score 0):

Check [GIS data for Singapore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17676/gis-data-for-singapore). The districts are already there, available to download in shapefile format.

Comment: I checked the link in given answer. data.gov.sg only provides survey district, not the actual districts. singstat link is broken.