# Cannot edit polygons in Qgis

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a google Layer map on top of which I have added a raster layer of Image and then mapped image coordinates from Google layer.

I made transparent (75%) image map layer and now mapping and creating polygons on top of image layer (Added new shapefile layer)
I drew few polygons and then saved it.

When I reopened the file, clicked on toggle editing, I could see my polygons, but I am not able to add/edit/delete existing/new polygons in that shapefile layer. (All icons are disabled)

Is this expected behavior?

My old question on what exactly am I doing.
[How to create/obtain district data for Singapore?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144848/how-to-create-obtain-district-data-for-singapore)

Comment: Have you tried saving and restarting QGIS? When I've had similar errors this can resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Did not work

Comment: Have you checked file permissions for the newly created shapefile? Is it writeable?

Comment: have you ensured that your shapefile layer is highlighted in the layer list(left side)? I think it might be needed for the editing tools to be active.

Comment: I created it. So I should have the write permission. I also updated it to give all permissions to all users. Didnt help

Comment: Yes, I did highlight my shape file, and then clicked on toggle edit.

Comment: Ofcourse @phil. I am sorry if that sounded rude. I updated permissions of that file and restarted qgis. Still same thing

Comment: I have added link to my shape file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnd3sgsdue2ohah/my_polygon.shp?dl=0

Comment: Would you need supporting files as well? I am sorry, I am new in this field. So not sure

Comment: There should be a .shp, a .dbf and a .shx file see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Overview. You can zip them up in to one archive if that's easier.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/laoai7bwuwkeprl/my_polygon.zip?dl=0

Comment: My QGIS can open and edit the file allright, but when saving the edits weird things happen: the new polygon jumps to a different position. ArcGIS cannot open the shape file even if I rename the .dbf to "my_polygon.dbf", complains about different number of shapes in shapefile and attribute table.
I suggest something is broken with the shape file.
Just for the record: what projection is the shapefile in? I assumed 4326 (WGS84).

Comment: There were multiple polygons, that I created and then merged few of them. Not sure, if that is the issue

Comment: Its in EPSG(3857) WGS 84

Comment: Compared to @til_b I can open the file and enter edit mode, but can only move features or edit nodes; I can't delete or edit features. There are multiple overlapping polygons in that shapefile. I wonder if this is causing the problem?

Comment: I wonder if your issue is related to [this bug](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4880) in which case you may be creating issues with intersections/holes due to number of polygons added. If it were me, I'd maybe start a fresh layer to test and ensure the polygons snap together.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple polygons overlapping. The reason is, I need to create a single large polygon, but the shape of polygon is in such a format, that it cannot be done at once. So i created multiple polygons, with some overlapping so that there is no merging issue.  Then i merged those polygons

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this on both my laptop (OS X) and my desktop (Ubuntu) but not a Windows box. As @til_b says, the problem seems to be that the `.dbf` has a different name to the `.shp` and `.shx` files.

After renaming the file behaved much better.

I also suggest you dissolve the layer using `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve` toolset.

After dissolving I was able to add, delete and edit features.